# why might the "exit" command in a linux shell not work?

Tags: linux, csh, tcsh

I have a user which hangs when he runs a csh script that doesn nothing byt "exit"...

```
# This is the x.csh script
exit
```

Then he...

```
tcsh x.csh
```

It hangs.

"which exit" gives "exit: shell built-in command."

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this as stated. `tcsh x.csh` exits immediately. `which exit` also says `shell built-in command`

Comment: Maybe he has an alias for `exit`.

Comment: Maybe he has an alias for `tcsh`!

Answer (score 1):

The .history file was corrupted.  Once removed, it worked as expected.